# Fill combo by an array on a web form in c # .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datetime-format

I have four variables of Long DateTime type, I want to fill combo with the help of these four values on a web page (using c sharp), The combo should show the name of Month of corresponding datetime variable,
How can ido that?

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "C# .NET". The language is C# and the platform is .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a Datatable for this purpose.
Simply say,

```
 ddlName.DataSource = dataableName;

 ddl.DataValueField = "ColumnName";

 ddl.DataTextField = "ColumnName";
```

Store the desired Values in respective columns and simply write their names against text or value fields.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to populate the combobox at runtime on your ASP.NET page in an unbound manner.  If this is the case, you would use the following code:

```
yourCombo.Items.Add(date1.ToString("MMMM"));
yourCombo.Items.Add(date2.ToString("MMMM"));
yourCombo.Items.Add(date3.ToString("MMMM"));
yourCombo.Items.Add(date4.ToString("MMMM"));
```

This will show your four variables in the combobox with their full month name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Action<DateTime> addItem = dateTime => 
    dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(dateTime.ToString("MMMM"), dateTime.ToString("O")));

addItem(dateTime1);
addItem(dateTime2);
addItem(dateTime3);
addItem(dateTime4);
```

or just add a mentod

```
private void AddItem(DateTime dateTime)
{
    dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(dateTime.ToString("MMMM"), dateTime.ToString("O")));
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddItem(dateTime1);
    AddItem(dateTime2);
    AddItem(dateTime3);
    AddItem(dateTime4);
}
```

Comment: @Khaleel - If any answer worked for can you please mark answer a correct answer. Thank you.