# Fill combo by variables on a web form in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datetime-format

I have to fill a combo on a web form with the help of four variables of long datetime,
I have to show only month names corresponding to datetime value when the combo opens,
How can i set these properties

1. DataTextField and
2. DataValueField

I have also to get longdatetime value corresponding to the selected Month in combo....

Comment: i don't hav installed vs on my new pc, can u check if u can bind arraylist with combo, then fill arraylist with values of ur choice

Comment: i'll vote for alex :), a better or a conventional solution

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169275/fill-combo-by-an-array-on-a-web-form-in-c-net

Answer (score 2):

You can add your four items like this:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(dateTime.ToString("MMMM"), dateTime.ToString("O")));
```

If you do it this way, then you can get selected datetime like this:

```
var selectedDateTime = DateTime.Parse(dropDownList.SelectedValue);
var longDateTimeString = selectedDateTime.ToLongDateString();
```

**[Edit]**

If your input variable are string variables, than you can do something like this:

```
var longDateString = "Sunday, May 29, 2011";
var monthString = DateTime.Parse(longDateString).ToString("MMMM");
dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(monthString, longDateString));
```

Comment: The value field should be 
datetime.ToLongDateString() //or some method similar to that.

Comment: @AD.Net - why does it have to be `LongDateString`? We just need to serialize datetime. If it is required to have date only, then it makes more sense to use `ShortDateString`, as this string needs less space in your html.

Comment: Because the poster mentioned he needs to get longdatetime of the selected date.